# Mongoose: exclude _id field in inserts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a high-concurrency and parallelism situation and would like _id fields to be created by MongoDB and not by mongoose, so that I can use the [ObjectId timestamps](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps) in the _id field to reliably query documents in the order they were inserted.

Is this possible? Right now I don't see how to do this with mongoose, as marking a schema with `{_id: false}` and trying to save it returns an error `document must have an _id before saving`.

Answer (score 2):

Mongoose docs say the _id option only works on subdocuments, hence the error you get (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id).

It might fit your situation to add a document without mongoose and in a subsequent operation update it through using mongoose (thereby keeping mongoose's Schema functionality etc).

Comment: I really wanted to avoid circumventing mongoose and using the mongodb driver directly. But seeing that there are no other responses, to my query, perhaps that is really the only option.